# Javascript string split issue in arabic/persian strings

Tags: javascript, arabic

i am trying to split two persian characters using the javascript string split but it is not splitting properly.

```
var test = '"حسن روحانی"،"حسن+روحانی"';
var tmpkeywords =  test.split(',');
console.log(tmpkeywords);
```

the split result should be like :

```
[""حسن روحانی""،""حسن+روحانی""]
```

but instead it is coming like `[""حسن روحانی"،"حسن+روحانی"↵"]`. It works well in English characters or numbers.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tueo3sfa/1/

Comment: Because `،` (U+060C ARABIC COMMA) is not `,` (U+002C COMMA), just change to `split('،')`. If it's a general purpose function (split by comma, regardless language) then you may use unicode classes (there are many many commas out there...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti strange that it splits anyway

Comment: thanks @AdrianoRepetti   i did not see that.

Comment: @Adelin it returns the entire string, as expected IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `"حسن روحانی"،"حسن+روحانی"` does not contain the character "`,`" (U+002C COMMA) but "`،`" (U+060C ARABIC COMMA): that is why it will not split and return just the whole original string.

To get what you want, you will need to split by "`،`"

```
var test = '"حسن روحانی"،"حسن+روحانی"';
var tmpkeywords =  test.split(',');
console.log(tmpkeywords);
```

Also note that there are many different commas in other languages, if you need to handle them in a generic way you may want to specify them all (raw unfiltered list http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=comma&han=Y&preview=entity) or, if applicable, to use Unicode classes (for example splitting by punctuation characters, see also http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset for an example).

Comment: It has already been said in comments. You're welcome to post it as answer but please add some more value to what it's already there.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti sorry, new to this, and I did not see the comment when I was writing it, sorry!

Comment: Don't worry, it's even perfectly OK (and encouraged!) to repost a comment as answer. Just add some more information.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thank you so much :) and thanks for the edits! Have a nice day! :)